# Get output from curl executed in PHP

Tags: php, xml, shell, curl, exec

I am using sonicAPI to try and upload a file. For some reason I cannot do this using curl within php because their api requires the flag -F which emulated posting from a form....((HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button)

Anyway. I have to use

```
exec("$curl https://api.sonicapi.com/file/upload?access_id=$accessId -Ffile=@./shortaudio.mp3 2>&1", $output, $exit);
```

to upload the file. The command in the quotation marks works when entered directly into a shell. It returns an xml string. However, when I var_dump($output), I just get the 'loading' information that is not actually shown in when executing it in an actual shell. I get this

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(79) "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current"
  [1]=>
  string(77) "                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed"
  [2]=>
  string(158) "
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 17008  100   249  100 16759    393  26489 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26517"
  [3]=>
  string(249) ""
}
```

How do I get the xml string that should be returned? The file does get uploaded successfully, so there defo should be an xml response.
Or, if not, how do I emulate form posting via php curl?

Comment: You should be able to do this in PHP (5.5+) using [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php)

Comment: hmm...still getting that 400 error. Using this  $cfile = curl_file_create("shortaudio.mp3",'multipart/form-data','shortaudio');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, the equivalent PHP `curl_` code is

```
$ch = curl_init ( 'https://api.sonicapi.com/file/upload?access_id=' . $accessId );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array (
                'file'=>new CURLFile('shortaudio.mp3')
        ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true
) );
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use -o file.xml to save the xml response